# How to use Chart UI in Nativescript

Tags: angular, charts, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm pretty new to Nativescript and currently working on a small test project using Angular and Typescript. Currently I am working with the charts option and have installed the Nativescript-ui-chart using 'tns plugin add nativescript-ui-chart' command. I can get the app to run, but nothing but blank space is displayed.

**My HTML file:**

```
<ActionBar>
    <NavigationButton title="Main Chart"></NavigationButton>
</ActionBar>

<StackLayout horizontalAlignment="center">

    <RadCartesianChart xmlns:chart="nativescript-ui-chart">
        <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis></CategoricalAxis>
        <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis></LinearAxis>

        <LineSeries tkCartesianSeries
            [item]="downloads"
            categoryProperty="month"
            valueProperty="downloads"></LineSeries>
    </RadCartesianChart>

</StackLayout>
```

**My Typescript file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-main-chart',
  templateUrl: './main-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-chart.component.css'],
  moduleId: module.id
})
export class MainChartComponent{

    downloads = [
        { month: "Jan1", downloads: 58863 },
        { month: "Jan2", downloads: 10000 },
        { month: "Jan3", downloads: 68863 },
        { month: "Jan4", downloads: 8863 },
        { month: "Jan5", downloads: 88863 },
        { month: "Jan6", downloads: 98863 },
        { month: "Jan7", downloads: 108863 },
        { month: "Jan8", downloads: 28863 }
    ];
}
```

I have added 
import { NativeScriptUIChartModule } from "nativescript-ui-chart/angular";
to my app.module file

**My app.module file:**

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AddTaskComponent } from './components/add-task/add-task.component';

import { CreateTaskComponent } from './components/create-task/create-task.component';
import { appComponents, appRoutes } from "./app.routing";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import { MainChartComponent } from './components/main-chart/main-chart.component';

import { NativeScriptUIChartModule } from "nativescript-ui-chart/angular";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule
        NativeScriptUIChartModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AddTaskComponent,
        CreateTaskComponent,
        MainChartComponent,
        ...appComponents   //imports all pages
    ],
    providers: [],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Also if this is iOS then it's your layout bc iOS doesn't know what you want this layout to do. Set a size on some of the UI and it'll render fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be problem with your layout. Try changing StackLayout to GridLayout or provide height and width to the same as well. I have created a sample playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=8zpRGL&v=565).

```
<GridLayout>
    <RadCartesianChart>
        <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis></CategoricalAxis>
        <LinearAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis></LinearAxis>
        <BarSeries tkCartesianSeries [items]="downloads" categoryProperty="month"
            valueProperty="downloads"></BarSeries>
    </RadCartesianChart>
</GridLayout>
```